# iOS 5: UILabel change size dynamically

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I am using storyboard and custom cells. In one of my labels I drugged on custom cell I need to print date. If date is arabic one, then I need to make label wider and print both dates -> arabic and christian.

My problem is that I am trying to access my label and change size:

```
 if(str.length==ARABIC_DATE)
    {
        cell.lblYears.layer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 10.0); 
        cell.lblYears.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        cell.lblYears.text=str;
    }
    else 
    {
        cell.lblYears.text=str;
    }
```

The result is an additional label in wrong place (0.0, 0.0..). How to make that code will not produce an additional label, but will change the existing.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not creating a second label in this code. You are placing an existing label in the (0,0) coordinate and setting 50 to the width and 10 to the height.

I don't know what your problem is exactly, but there is nothing wrong in that piece of code.

Comment: Ok. how to access x,y of my existing label?

Comment: You are already accessing them. The first two parameters of `CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 10.0);` are `x` and `y`. You are setting both to 0.

Comment: I mean how to get x and y programmatically without just inputing the float values directly.

Comment: Got it cell.lblYears.frame.origin.x